# Can sed save its output to a file?

Tags: sed, io-redirection

`>` can do it.

```
echo "text" > file
```

`tee` can do it.

```
echo "test" | tee file
```

Can `sed` do it without using either of the above? Is it possible to save the output of a `sed` command to a file without using either `>` or `tee`?

Comment: Please try to find the answer yourself before posting questions here. The first thing we ask of our users is to [search and research](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. All you needed to do was `sed '' file > newfile` and you would have seen that `>` can indeed be used with `sed` just like with any other program.

Comment: That's still using the `>` operator. I was interested if there were a sed command that could be used instead. But I'll delete this question if it's so bad.

Comment: Ah, right. OK, that's a very different question. Since you accepted the `sed -i` answer, I'll edit your question and clarify what you're after.

Comment: I accepted "`sed `is not meant for data redirection as `tee` and `>` (are) meant to be".

Answer (score 137, accepted):

tee and > can be used for data redirection because these are meant to be used for data redirection in linux.

sed on the other hand is a stream editor. sed is not meant for data redirection as tee and > meant to be. However you can use conjunction of commands to do that.

use tee or > with sed

```
sed 's/Hello/Hi/g' file-name | tee file
```

or

```
sed 's/Hello/Hi/g' file-name > file
```

use sed with -i option

```
sed -i 's/Hello/Hi/g' file-name
```

the last one does not redirect, instead it will make changes in the file itself.

Comment: Thanks. You understood my question. So the answer is no. I thought `sed` on it's own maybe could do it, because it's also capable of creating backup files with the `-i.bak` option.

Comment: Correct. Also -i.bak is not a fixed option, you can use any extension, which you would like your backup file to have. for ex. -i.log will also work. :)

Comment: I just like to add that was actually looking for `echo "test" | dd of=file status=none`, suppressing an echo's output without using the obscure output redirection `2> /dev/null`, but instead asked for sed's limitations. I was really impressed by sed's abilities as it's capable of appending lines in file, giving me the impression that sed could do anything tee could do and more.

Comment: Doesn't work with `-i`: `sed: 1: "pubspec.yaml": extra characters at the end of p command`. My command: `sed -i 's/version:.*/version: 0.0.11+4/g' pubspec.yaml`

Comment: The last option will not create the file, unfortunately

Comment: instead it is modifying the current file @Ari

Comment: Becareful with `sed 's/Hello/Hi/g' file-name > file` if `file-name == file` refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198627/7813311)

Answer (score 15):

`sed` has the `w` command that might do what you require:

> **w filename**
>
> Write the current pattern space to filename.

`sed 'w file'` on its own will have the same effect as `tee file`.  If there are other sed commands, put the `w` last:

```
sed 's/This/That/;w file'
```

However, this won't be affected by the `-n/--quiet/--silent` option.  That only suppresses the content that would otherwise have gone to standard output.

Answer (score 4):

As ankidaemon correctly pointed out how we can save sed output to a file. I would like to add that if we are performing some operations on a file i.e replace and would like to save the output to the same file. There is a `-i` flag in `sed` which makes inplace edits possible. This however creates a backup file in the process if a suffix is provided as argument. If that's not needed, that can be done by just passing empty filename or nothing to `-i` flag.

Example: `sed -i "s/from/to/" file` is inplace changing the `file`.

Comment: example: `sed -i '' "s/BAD/GOOD/" file.yml`